# How to read the JComboBox values from a column in a JTable with multiples lines

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Once I have a `JTable` with many lines and each line has a column with a `JComboBox`, how to I read the column? I have been struggling with many classes and getting the components, but so far I can not get the combo box handle to remove, read or add item dynamically. I need to add values to the combo box dynamically (now they are static), remove them and then save to the database. `getValueAt(row, col)` only gives me the value of the object but not the instance of the combo box to manipulate it, maybe I don't have the correct approach.

This is how I created it:

```
private void startup() {
    String[] values = {"001-abc", "002-fgh, "003-xyz"};

    TableColumn comboCol15 = this.table.getColumnModel().getColumn(15);
    comboCol15.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(getComboBox(values)));
}

private JComboBox getComboBox(String[] values) {
    if (comboBox == null) {
        comboBox = new JComboBox();
    }
    if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
        comboBox.removeAllItems();
        for (String key : values) {
            comboBox.addItem(key);
        }
    }
    return comboBox;
```

Comment: Consider creating a [mcve] in order to get help sooner.

Comment: How did you create it?

Comment: Use getValueAt to get the Object.

Comment: Example added, thanks.

Comment: Tips: 1) Add @GeorgeZ. (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) What's been posted above, is ***not* an MRE.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
ComboBoxTableCellEditor editor = new ComboBoxTableCellEditor();
```

TableColumn comboCol15 = this.tableFacturacion.getColumnModel().getColumn(15);
comboCol15.setCellEditor(editor);

```
ComboBoxTableCellEditor editor  = (ComboBoxTableCellEditor)this.tableFacturacion.getCellEditor(0, 15);
```

JComboBox combobox = editor.getComboBox();
combobox.addItem("hola");

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, [edit] the answer, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.